# How to trigger click on "Save to Google Drive" button

Tags: google-drive-api

How to trigger "click" on Save to Google Drive button, i mean, i have my own design for "Save to Google Drive" button.
is there any programaticly trigger to open "save to google drive" popups in Javascript?

Thanks

**EDIT**

i want to modify this api

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#getting_started

Comment: Find out which endpoint the button is calling and make the call yourself.

Comment: What exactly are you saving to google drive? Can't you set the 'on-click' html attribute of the button to use the API or do whatever else you want?

Comment: yes, i mean to set the "on-click" event to popup the "save to google drive" api, (not uploading it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

html:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Save to Drive</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="doitButton" value="Save Chat History in Drive">
  <input type="button" id="authorizeButton" value="Authorize" onClick="checkAuth()">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

js:

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

function handleClientLoad() {
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
}

function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': SCOPES,
    'immediate': true
  }, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  var authButton = document.getElementById('authorizeButton');
  var doitButton = document.getElementById('doitButton');
  authButton.style.display = 'none';
  doitButton.style.display = 'none';
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to
    // the API.
    doitButton.style.display = 'block';
    doitButton.onclick = uploadFile;
  } else {
    // No access token could be retrieved, show the button to start the
    // authorization flow.
    authButton.style.display = 'block';
    authButton.onclick = function() {
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES,
        'immediate': false
      }, handleAuthResult);
    };
  }
}

function uploadFile(evt) {
  gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
    insertFile();
  });
}

function insertFile() {
  //YOUR INSERT CODE
}
```

As you can see, the `handleAuthResult()` get the OAuth result and conditionally check the authorization then if successful will add onclick="uploadFile()".