# Trigger click on Save To Drive button

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the [Save to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive) button from Google Drive's API but with a custom look. My objective is to hide the button and trigger its click event so the save window pops up. However, I cannot find a way to trigger the click event on the button. I have tried calling `click()` and `dispatchEvent()` on the button's div without success. It appears as that the script uses `addEventListener` since nothing is assigned to either `onclick`, `onmouseup` or `onmousedown` on the button's div.

Using DOM event breakpoints in chrome dev tools I can see what code is called when I click the button (and it seems that the script uses the `'mouseup'` event) but I cannot understand what's going on since the code is minified (and maybe obfuscated? I can't tell).

**I know this has been asked before** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581127/how-to-trigger-click-on-save-to-google-drive-button), but the answer, instead of triggering the click on the button, uses the Google Drive API, which I want to avoid because I do not want to go through all Google's verification process to be able to access the `drive` scope.

Has anyone managed to do this before? Any ideas on what I can try?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered it is impossible to do this. Since the button is in an iframe element, the browser prevents Javascript from accessing it.